# How to rename the Existing Excel file with Current date and time using Selenium web Driver?

Tags: java, testing, selenium-webdriver

Filepath i am using but its not taking the current date and time

```
public static String FilePath="C:\\Users\\skumari1\\eclipse-workspace\\CoreLinkAutomation\\src\\main\\java\\com\\corelink\\testData\\PCPAutomation.xlsx"+ PrimaryCommonSetDataUTil.Validatedate();
```

For current date and time using this code

```
public static String Validatedate() {

    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    Date date = new Date();
    String date1= dateFormat.format(date);
    // System.out.println("Current date and time is " +date1);
    return date1;
}
```

For writing data into Excel file using this code but i want to rename the Filepath

```
public static void write_test_result(String result, String sheet_name, String filePath,int row_num,int col_num) throws EncryptedDocumentException, FileNotFoundException, IOException
{
    Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream(filePath));
    Sheet sh = wb.getSheet(sheet_name);
    
    sh.getRow(row_num).createCell(col_num).setCellValue(result);
    
    wb.write(new FileOutputStream(filePath));
}
```

I want after every execution of project the filepath should be renamed as Filepath+Current date and time.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of date you are using contains / and : which is invalid for a file name. Use a format that is valid as a file name. For example:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy_HH_mm_ss");
```

Comment: C:\Users\skumari1\eclipse-workspace\CoreLinkAutomation\src\main\java\com\corelink\testData\PCPAutomation.xlsx07-24-2020_14_33_14 (The system cannot find the file specified)--->using this I am getting File not found Exception because its checking the Filepath with Current date and time which is not available, need to change the Filepath name everytime then need to execute it.

Comment: Please show full code how you are calling the write_test_result method. I can see that you have declared a static fileName variable on top but using method variable filename as well. Please share full code.